# Sum about An Introduction to Ramanujan's notebooks

Tags: calculus

I see a similar formula in Ramanujan's notebooks but not proof
$$-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\csc (2 k)}{2 k (2 k+1)^2 \zeta '(-2 k)}+\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left(\frac{1}{(\pi  k+1)^2 \zeta (-k \pi )}-\frac{1}{(\pi  k-1)^2 \zeta (k \pi )}\right) \sec (\pi  k)}{\pi  k}+4-2 \log (2 \pi )=$$ $$\csc(1)$$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } -\frac{8 ((2 \pi  k+1) \zeta (-k \pi )+(1-2 \pi  k) \zeta (k \pi )) \sec (\pi  k)}{\left(1-4 \pi ^2 k^2\right)^2 \zeta (-k \pi ) \zeta (k \pi )}-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{8 \csc (2 k)}{(4 k-1) (4 k+1)^2 \zeta '(-2 k)}+\frac{\csc \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}+\frac{\csc \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}+16=\frac{-6 \zeta '(\pi )^2+3 \zeta (\pi ) \zeta ''(\pi )-\zeta (\pi )^2}{6 \zeta (\pi )^3}$$
I am curiosity where it it get it??

Comment: in fact the sum is mine, but it is similar to those that appear in the notebooks, the question is expected some contribution but it is difficult to recover, I imagine that they will close the question because they have nothing to contribute

Comment: Something is missing at the end $\csc$ of what ? Don't close the question, please.

Comment: no I do not close the question but somebody will do sure... thanks for your Comments Claude

Comment: I shall work on it tomorrow morning. I have to go now.

Comment: Not that it is at all a critique, but just my own curiosity; but why do you decide to use $\sec(\pi k)$ instead of $(-1)^k$?

Comment: Perhaps it just makes more clear an elegant pattern that I'm not seeing.

Comment: you are  right is because I'm lazy and I have not simplified the expression